# Ux of conditional logic when numbered questions

Tags: forms, logic, questionnaire

I would like to apply conditional logic to a questionnaire to make it slimmer and easier to complete for our users. The new questions will appear dynamically appear on the page, under the trigger questions.
Ex: 
How many employees work for the company apart from the founders? 
(if 0, question is not displayed if > 0, question will dynamically appear)

However, the questions need to be numbered: 
1. How many employees work for the company apart from the founders?

How will I deal with the appearance of the numbers? Because until when the question appears (if it does), users will see skipped numbers and I believe that's not good, but I wouldn't know how to do otherwise. It will appear like this: 
1. How many employees work for the company apart from the founders? 
3. Where is the company based

Do you have any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: The question is even more true in case they are not sequential. I was thinking is that I could do the opposite: always display all questions and hide in case the following questions don't apply (e.g. make 1a and 1b disappear). What do you think about it? But in this case should I leave a notification text not to disorient the user (e.g. Q2 and 3 were skipped because you have no employees)?

Comment: – Are all the questions displayed one after the other in a scrollable page?

– Being the questionnaire conditional I guess the user cannot leave question 4 blank and jump to question 10, respond and then go back to question 6 right? so she always needs to go from 1 to 2 (if the condition is true) then 3, then 4, etc

– Do the user needs to know the total number of questions to answer in order to finish the questionnaire?

Comment: Why must the questions be numbered? For which purpose?

Comment: You might not need to number them after all. Maybe you can try to group them in categories, and show only the relevant questions while filling up the form.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the "trigger" questions (i.e. the questions that produce follow-up questions) can be numbered, but the follow-up questions can have a secondary numbering system. This would enable you to omit the dependent questions when they don't apply without causing any jarring renumbering or causing the user to feel like they missed something.

For example:

> **1. How many employees work for the company apart from the founders?** 46
>
> **1.a. Approximately what percentage of these employees are full-time?** 70%
>
> **1.b. Do any employees work 100% remotely?** Yes
>
> **2. Where is the company based?** The moon

Comment: Yes, but if they are not sequential? What I was thinking is that I could do the opposite: always display all questions and hide in case the following questions don't apply (e.g. make 1a and 1b disappear). What do you think about it? But in this case should I leave a notification text not to disorient the user (e.g. Q2 and 3 were skipped because you have no employees)?

Comment: I thought you were talking about "numbered questions", which would be sequential.. In either case, I'd definitely recommend only showing them if they apply. If, for example, there are 30 possible questions, but only 18 of them apply to a specific user, why make them read the other 12? They have no need to be presented with follow up questions that don't apply (which would presumably be disabled anyways).